# SharePoint 2010, InfoPath and top-level list lookup

Tags: infopath, lookup-column

We want to have some lists (Suppliers, Projects, etc) at top-site level which can be reached by all child-sites.
Using InfoPath on child-sites we want to have a lookup field in the lists there so we can choose Supplier, Project, etc.

Also it is important that changes to the list at top-site level are reflected to sub-sites using the list.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the columns available in subsites, you'd want to create site columns.  These site columns for supplier and project would then be available everywhere below the root site.

Using InfoPath you'd want to add a drop down control on your page and point the data source to the SharePoint list (Right click the control, Drop Down List Properties, click Get choices from an external data source, click Add and follow the wizard).

Then you can choose to promote the column to a lookup field or text field in the desired form library.